# Updating Navigation panel style in dependence of what being rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a hoc, which renders the following:

```
  render() {
            return (
                <div className={classes.Layout}>
                    <Toolbar color={this.state.color} />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
                        <Route path='/treechart' render={props => (
                            <TreeChart />
                        )} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            )

        }
```

My goal is to make Toolbar to have different colors when different routes are active. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use location and withRouter from react-router.

```
withRouter(YourComponent)
```

What this does is provide location as prop to your component.
You can then acess the current path using this.props.location.pathname and set color accordingly.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/location.md